# Configure AdminClientProperties for Spring Cloud Stream Kafka with AWS_MSK_IAM authentication

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, amazon-iam, spring-cloud-stream, aws-msk

From a Spring Boot App, I'm trying to connect consumers to Kafka using AWS_MSK_IAM as the `sasl.mechanism`, but I'm having trouble with the configuration. Here are my attempts:

```
spring.cloud.stream:
  kafka:
  binder:
    brokers: <REDACTED>
    consumerProperties:
      security.protocol: SASL_SSL
      sasl.mechanism: AWS_MSK_IAM
      sasl.jaas.config: software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
      sasl.client.callback.handler.class: software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler

spring.cloud.stream:
  kafka:
  binder:
    brokers: <REDACTED>
    configuration:
      security.protocol: SASL_SSL
      sasl.mechanism: AWS_MSK_IAM
      sasl.jaas.config: software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
      sasl.client.callback.handler.class: software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
```

In both cases, I get the same errors:

```
{ [-] 
    level:  ERROR 
    logger:  org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService 
    message:  Failed to create consumer binding; retrying in 30 seconds 
    parentId:  329a1af3d011a941 
    spanId:  62d1b59a45687e35 
    thread:  scheduling-1 
    throwable: { [-] 
      cause: { [-] 
        class:  java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException 
        msg:  null 
        stack: [ [-] 
          org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:108) 
          org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:272) 
          org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicAndPartitions(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:383) 
          org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicIfNecessary(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:357) 
          org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:334) 
          org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.doProvisionConsumerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:231) 
          org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionConsumerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:197) 
          org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionConsumerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:86) 
          org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:403) 
          org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:91) 
          org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindConsumer(AbstractBinder.java:143) 
          org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.lambda$rescheduleConsumerBinding$1(BindingService.java:202) 
          org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:63) 
          org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) 
          java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) 
          java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) 
          java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) 
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
          java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) 
       ] 
     } 
      class:  org.springframework.cloud.stream.provisioning.ProvisioningException 
      msg:  Provisioning exception encountered for topic-name; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException 
      stack: [ [-] 
        org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:347) 
        org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.doProvisionConsumerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:231) 
        org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionConsumerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:197) 
        org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionConsumerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:86) 
        org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:403) 
        org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:91) 
        org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindConsumer(AbstractBinder.java:143) 
        org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.lambda$rescheduleConsumerBinding$1(BindingService.java:202) 
        org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:63) 
        org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) 
        java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) 
        java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) 
        java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) 
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) 
     ] 
   } 
    timestamp:  2022-01-27T20:29:03,384Z 
    traceId:  329a1af3d011a941 
}


  { [-] 
        level:  INFO 
        logger:  org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig 
        message:  AdminClientConfig values: 
          bootstrap.servers = <REDACTED>
          client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
          client.id = 
          connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
          default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
          metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
          metric.reporters = []
          metrics.num.samples = 2
          metrics.recording.level = INFO
          metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
          receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
          reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
          reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
          request.timeout.ms = 30000
          retries = 2147483647
          retry.backoff.ms = 100
          sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
          sasl.jaas.config = null
          sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
          sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
          sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
          sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
          sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
          sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
          sasl.login.class = null
          sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
          sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
          sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
          sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
          sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
          security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
          security.providers = null
          send.buffer.bytes = 131072
          socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 127000
          socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
          ssl.cipher.suites = null
          ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
          ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
          ssl.engine.factory.class = null
          ssl.key.password = null
          ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
          ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
          ssl.keystore.key = null
          ssl.keystore.location = null
          ssl.keystore.password = null
          ssl.keystore.type = JKS
          ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
          ssl.provider = null
          ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
          ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
          ssl.truststore.certificates = null
          ssl.truststore.location = null
          ssl.truststore.password = null
          ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    }
```

Note that in the `AdminClientConfig` values, `sasl.jaas.config = null`. It looks like my properties aren't being picked up for AdminClientConfig. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure what's going on. Here is a sample that works. Please compare with that. Try if you can recreate locally against a cluster.

Comment: @sobychacko I think you forgot the sample?

Comment: Oh. Sorry about that. Here it is: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/kafka-security-samples/kafka-ssl-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This configuration worked. It's nearly identical to my second attempt in the question, but I fixed the indentation.

```
spring.cloud.stream:
  kafka:
    binder:
      brokers: <REDACTED>
      configuration:
        security.protocol: SASL_SSL
        sasl.mechanism: AWS_MSK_IAM
        sasl.jaas.config: software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class: software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
```